# Could not HEAD https://www.jitpack.io/org/jitsi/react/jitsi-meet-sdk/5.1.0/jitsi-meet-sdk-5.1.0.pom Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

Tags: react-native, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I was integrating react-native-jitsi-meet in my app and when building this error shows up

```
Could not resolve org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:5.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-jitsi-meet
      > Could not resolve org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:5.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://www.jitpack.io/org/jitsi/react/jitsi-meet-sdk/5.1.0/jitsi-meet-sdk-5.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://www.jitpack.io/org/jitsi/react/jitsi-meet-sdk/5.1.0/jitsi-meet-sdk-5.1.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

I have implemented all the configs they shown in docs.

In doc they asked me to change repository in allprojects like this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven { // <---- Add this block
            url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

But in my project there was no allProjects, but I had repositories

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { 
            url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
        }
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}
```

Can this cause that error. Others all I did exactly like they mentioned. Please tell where I am wrong.